# JMeter - How can I check mail count in gmail box thread by thread

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, test-strategy

I'd like to connect `gmail` server before user thread group, and I wanna open inbox and check mail count in every user interaction.

1. Connect gmail ones
2. Check registration emails many times (100, 1000)
3. Close gmail connection.

How can I do this?

My `JMeter` project as in picture

[image]

setUp is a BeanShell sampler

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import javax.mail.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Properties sessionProps = new Properties();
String sTo = "";
String token = "";

sessionProps.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(sessionProps);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("${mailHost}", "${mailUser}", "${mailPassword}");
log.info("Store: " + store);

vars.putObject("store", store);
${__setProperty("store1", store)}
props.set("store2", store)

log.info("Mailbox opened. - " + vars.getObject("store"));
```

tearDown is a BeanShell sampler

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import javax.mail.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Store store = vars.getObject("store");
store.close();

log.info("Mailbox closed.");
```

getValidationToken is a BeanShell sampler too

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import javax.mail.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Store store = vars.getObject("store");
// Strore store = props.get("store")
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

int msgCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
log.info("Count: " + msgCount);
```

---

My problem is I wanna one store (connect ones to mailbox) like a `JDBC Connection Configuration`. After this in the `userRegistration` section

1. Send a HTTP request with following body data:

   { "userId" : "${__P(registeredMail${__threadNum})}"}
2. Read token from response mail generated/sent by back end what placed in the mailbox.
3. Do next step with this token.

I don't know is it clear enough, but if you have any ideas how to do it, please share any details.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of the following constraints:

1. [Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   It means that you can use `vars` within the bounds of one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) only and variables are [thread-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (each JMeter thread - virtual user - has its own set of variables)

   Properties are **global** so if you do something like `props.set("store2", store)` with user1 and then the same code will be executed by user2 - the value **will be overwritten** so I would rather recommend adding current thread number as prefix/postfix like:

   ```
   props.put("store_" + ctx.getThreadNum(), vars.getObject("store"));
   ```
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly for performance reasons, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for comprehensive explanation
3. As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation you should not be inlining JMeter functions and variables into scripts, moreover it's not very safe as they may resolve into something causing compilation failure or unexpected behaviour.